# using Windows Email Server for Heroku Setup

Tags: ruby, heroku, smtp, windows-server-2008

So I have my first ever Ruby website up and running and would like it to send out emails. Unforantately it is hosted on Heroku which doesn't have a email server which is free to use.

What I do have is a windows 2008 virtual server that runs other websites I have. These websites already make use of the smtp server that is part of windows server. They have access (asp.net projects) by simply having my web.config pointing at itself as the server

```
<smtp>
  <network host="localhost" port="25" />
</smtp>
```

I assume it is authenticating it as the user logged in, and this is how is currently is allowed to do it. If I wanted to make use of it from the project on heroku, how would I go about doing that.

What IIS/SMTP server setup would I need to do in windows?
And What code do I need to go about making use of it in my ruby project?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would really recommend that you look at the [SendGrid add-on](http://addons.heroku.com/sendgrid).  You get 200 emails / day and all the associated management for exactly zero of your earth dollars.  Should you need more than that it's still very low cost.

If you run your own server, you need to look after it, worry about connectivity, and latency.

SendGrid on Bamboo/Aspen for Rails is [pretty much zero setup](http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sendgrid), and only a small amount on Cedar.

Comment: super thanks for the info! still learning alot regarding the add-ons (and anything else related to ruby/heroku for that matter)